# How to send notification at specific date and time?

Tags: laravel, cron

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
$notifications = Notification::where('created_at',null)->where('notification_schedule','!=',null)->where('notification_schedule','<=',Carbon::now('Asia/Kathmandu')->toDateTimeString())->get();
        if(!empty($notifications))
        {
            foreach($notifications as $notification)
            {
                $year = Carbon::now('Asia/Kathmandu')->format('Y');
                $parsedNotificationSchedule = Carbon::parse($notification->notification_schedule);
                $notificationYear = $parsedNotificationSchedule->format('Y');
                $notificationDay = $parsedNotificationSchedule->format('d');
                $notificationMonth = $parsedNotificationSchedule->format('m');
                $notificationHour = $parsedNotificationSchedule->format('H');
                $notificationMinute = $parsedNotificationSchedule->format('i');
                $cron = $notificationHour.' '.$notificationMinute.' '.$notificationDay.' '. $notificationMonth.' *';
                $schedule->call(function () use($year,$notificationYear,$notification) {
                    if($year == $notificationYear){
                        $this->sendNotification($notification);
                    }
                })->cron($cron);
            }
        }

            
    }
```

```
protected function sendNotification($notification)
    {
        try {
            //process notification sent
            $data = json_decode($notification->detail,true);
            $data['is_scheduled'] = true;
            event(new NotificationEvent($data));
            $notification->created_at = Carbon::now($this->settings->first()->time_zone);
            $notification->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::error("exception when sending notification" . $e);
        }
    }
```

I want to send notification at a specific date and time. With laravel documentation i found out ->cron() can do this thing. But even after i configured the code in the kernel.php of console. it doens't even run.

Comment: Have you configured ```schedule:run``` in server cron jobs ?

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai yes

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your scheduler running. If the scheduler is not running your scheduled jobs will not be executed.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Schedular is running... When i change ->cron() to ->everyMinute() it works

Comment: @OurFacts is your application timezone correct?

Comment: Yes timezone is correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to start scheduler in background to run cron in laravel.

please put `php artisan schedule:run` command in background.

Comment: Schedular is running . when i change  ->cron() to ->everyMinute() it works

Answer (score 0):

You can call notification Class using **Schedule Frequency Options**

Like : ->cron('* * * * *') OR ->everyMinute() OR ...

For more information check documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling